# Creating PCB or breakout board for sensor/ICs

Tags: pcb, breakout

I want to buy a BMA180 accelerometer to learn programming SPI and I2C devices (the sensor supports both). This is the [link to the sensor on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-SENSOR-IC-BOSCH-LGA-12-BMA180-053-/400668625119?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d49b608df) and below is a picture of the sensor:

[image]

How do I work with that?

I haven't found a ready made breakout boards to solder it.

Should I buy an SOP to DIP converter?

Answer (score 1):

The [BMA180 accelerometer](http://irtfweb.ifa.hawaii.edu/~tcs3/jumpman/jumppc/1107-BMA180/BMA180-DataSheet-v2.5.pdf) is in an LGA package, i.e. no actual pins sticking out, unlike SOP / SOIC packages. This makes it non-trivial to hand-solder, even if a breakout board were available. The pin pitch of 0.5 mm makes this even more challenging.

Assembled breakout boards, with the IC already soldered in, are available from several sources: Searching for `BMA180 module` yielded [this one on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0088KB34G), for instance.

[image: BMA180 module]

Comment: Nice find, the only one I came across was made by Bosch, costs twice as much, and isn't in stock anywhere.

Comment: I know, but the sensor is cheap and together with the breakout is way too expensive. Thast why i thought diy

Comment: All the best. Do share your results here when you get done!